# renderd error: postgis plugin: could not connect to server

Tags: postgresql, render, postgis

My tileserver worked perfectly fine but my disk space went full. So I gave my VM more capacity, rebooted it and after I did everything I usually do I got that renderd error:

```
An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': Postgis Plugin: could not connect to server: No such file or directory  
Is the server running locally and accepting  
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?  
Connection string: ' dbname=gis connect_timeout=4'  
encountered during parsing of layer 'landcover-low-zoom' in Layer at line 755 of '/home/betrieb  /src/openstreetmap-carto/mapnik.xml'
```

How can I fix this that my tileserver runs fine again?
Thanks in advance :)

(correct my tags if they are wrong)
(crosspost to [OSM-Help](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/69819/renderd-error-postgis-plugin-could-not-connect-to-server))

Comment: Please do not put `solved` in the question's title. If you accept your answer, your question will automatically be marked as resolved.

Comment: I tried. Can't accept it for 2 days. That's why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Answer: Running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure postgresql` and then `sudo systemctl restart renderd`.